# Distributed cache usage using new api's

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to run the hadoop program using the new api's in hadoop. Can anyone guide me as to how I can use it the new api using setup methods.

**Mapper Class**

```
protected void setup(Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
      URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cacheFiles[0].toString()));
  }

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {

    ....?   // How should I access the above cached file here?
String line=br.readLine();
}
```

**Driver Class**

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
job.setJobName("wordcount");
job.setJarByClass(driver.class);

Configuration conf = new Configuration();         

job.addCacheFile(new Path("hdfs://master:54310/usr/local/hadoop/input/normal_small").toUri());
```

Here is what I got after searching, but I am not sure as to how I can access the cached file in the map method of the mapper class. Kindly mention the same.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193145/accessing-maxmind-geo-api-in-hadoop-using-distributed-cache/25295428#25295428

Comment: @Ashrith: I am getting an error  File does not exist: hdfs://master:54310/usr/local/hadoop/input/normal_small#inp